# How to put two metapost graphs in the same row in LuaLatex?

Tags: metapost

I draw graphs using metapost in LuaLatex. It is more convienient than first use metapost to create graphs and then insert the graphs. But I don't know how to put two graphs in the same row. For example, how to put the following two graphs in the same row? Thank you very much.

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{luamplib}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1)
pair A[],L[],R[],N[];
A[1] := (0,2cm);

for i=2 upto 5:
A[i] := A[i-1] rotated -360/5;
endfor;

draw A[1]--A[2];
draw A[2]--A[3];
draw A[3]--A[4];
draw A[4]--A[5];
draw A[5]--A[1];
draw A[1]--A[4];

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1)
pair A[],L[],R[],N[],t[];
path p[];

A[1] := (0,2cm);

for i=2 upto 5:
A[i] := A[i-1] rotated -360/5;
endfor;

draw A[1]..A[2]..A[3]..A[4]..A[5]..A[1];

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @MarcelKrüger, thank you very much for your suggestions. I edited the post.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger, I tried to write beginfig(1) and beginfig(2) in the same graph. But it is still in two rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In you document you use two figures. LaTeX never places multiple figures in the same row, so you have to place both `mplibcode` environments in the same `figure` environment. (You can also combine them into one `mplibcode` environment with multiple `beginfig(...) endfig;` groups, but using different `mplibcode` environemnts makes it easier to separate the drawings.

Then there is a remaining problem:
After `\begin{figure}`, TeX is in vertical mode.
If you add multiple `\hbox`es (through `mplibcode`) while vertical mode is active, TeX stacks them vertically.
So you want to enter horizontal mode first: Add `\leavevmode` before the first `mplibcode` environment:

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{luamplib}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[H]
  \leavevmode
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1)
pair A[],L[],R[],N[];
A[1] := (0,2cm);

for i=2 upto 5:
A[i] := A[i-1] rotated -360/5;
endfor;

draw A[1]--A[2];
draw A[2]--A[3];
draw A[3]--A[4];
draw A[4]--A[5];
draw A[5]--A[1];
draw A[1]--A[4];

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}% <- Omit this comment to add a space between the graphs.
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1)
pair A[],L[],R[],N[],t[];
path p[];

A[1] := (0,2cm);

for i=2 upto 5:
A[i] := A[i-1] rotated -360/5;
endfor;

draw A[1]..A[2]..A[3]..A[4]..A[5]..A[1];

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]